# Migrating Home Network/Server to IPv6

Tags: networking, ip, ipv6, ipv4, 6to4

So,

My current setup includes 2 internet connections via different ISPs coming into my multi-wan router (TL-R480T+) along with another connection from 4G Router. So, in all 3 internet connections.

Both ISP connections are load balanced and 4G connection is a failover.

And then somewhere inside my LAN (which includes a bunch of unmanaged routers and Google Wifi devices), I have my home-server, that I need to be accessible from outside.

All good. Everything works.

But now, I am switching ISPs and both the new ISPs provide dual stack IPv4/IPv6 connection but then IPv4 is via NAT (hence not public) and IPv6 is not supported by my router. So, while I will be able to access internet, I won't be able to reach my server from outside.

Since, I can't guarantee that I will always have an IPv6 connection available (and same for the users that access websites on my server). I need the server to be accessible via both IPv4 and IPv6 from outside - for HTTP, HTTPS and SSH

And I have been banging my head, searching for a way to do this.

Comment: You don't have a public IPv4, so people can't connect to your server over IPv4. Ask your ISPs if you can buy a static IPv4 address. Or consider migrating to a professionally hosted server if that's an option. I wouldn't be surprised if it turned out cheaper due to the economy of scale.

Comment: Already checked with my ISP, no static (or dynamic) public IPv4.

Can't move to hosted server - since the server provides access to home devices as well.

For reaching my network via IPv4, thinking of using Cloudflare IPv6 Gateway (https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-cloudflares-automatic-ipv6-gatewa/) for HTTP/HTTPS and probably a tunnel via a VPS for SSH (looking for options).

But this is only when I am able to reach the server via IPv6. Currently limited by router being IPv4 only. So looking for router options - 3 WANs, load-balancing/failover, Gigabit Ethernet, IPv6 support.

Comment: Sorry, product recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: @HarshMoorjani Your router doesn't offer IPv6 6to4 / 4to6?

Comment: That would be extremely rare, even the most basic hardware during the transition from IPv4 to IPv6 supported it it.

Comment: @JW0914 / Ramhound - no it doesn't. Infact my router is only IPv4 (TP-Link TL-R480T+) while the ISP modem-router doesn't support 6to4/4to6 (Nokia G-2425G-A) - or atleast I am not able to find any such option.

Comment: @HarshMoorjani Using a different router that supports IPv6 6to4/4to6 is the only solution I can think of. If you have a spare motherboard & RAM lying around, you could replace the R480T+ with a software router, such as [Sophos UTM](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/unified-threat-management.aspx) _(free for [home users](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/support/utm-downloads.aspx))_, else a consumer router with [OpenWrt support](https://openwrt.org/toh/views/toh_available_16128) would allow you to create a vLAN with the WAN port & 3 LAN ports, providing the same functionality as the R480T+.

Comment: @JW0914 - thought so, but my problem with that is... I need 3 WAN ports (and load balancing, failover etc)

Comment: @HarshMoorjani Both router solutions I mentioned allow you to bridge LAN and WAN ports in a vLAN to create however many WAN ports you need

Comment: @JW0914 - I tried learning a bit about "bridge LAN and WAN ports in a vLAN to create however many WAN ports" ... can't grasp the concept, have any link to share where it explains it well?

Comment: @HarshMoorjani In other words, if running a router OS/firmware that allows it, you would create a vLAN [virtual LAN] interface and include however many of the physical ports within it. Sophos UTM and OpenWrt both allow you to do so via their respective WebUIs _(I run both, with my primary WAN router running ESXi with Sophos UTM in a VM as a software appliance on a server board)_. Sophos UTM: create a bridge || OpenWrt: vLAN [man page](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/vlan/switch_configuration) and example of the [switch config](https://pastebin.com/gD66LB9T) in `/etc/config/network`